# Regarding SQL Server query and joining

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Basically I have 3 tables `user`, `colors` and `usercolor`.

Table structure:

- `User` table has columns like `UserID`, `UserName`
- `Color` table has columns like `ColorID`, `ColorName`
- `UserColor` table has columns `UserID`, `ColorID`

When user login and go to my view first time then all color will be fetch and show in view with checkboxes as a result user can select any or many.

When any user select any color or many color from UI and save in db then userid and color id will be saved in user colors table but the same user again come to view then all colors will be show and if he previously selected anyone then those color name checkbox will be shown as checked.

I prepare a SQL statement to fetch all color data joining two table `colors` & `usercolor`, but the moment I specify `userid` then one records is fetching that is not right. I want to show always all distinct color name for every user and if user selected any then that color name show be shown by selected checkbox.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Colors.ColorID, dbo.Colors.ColorName, 
    ISNULL(dbo.UserColor.UserID, 0) AS IsSelected
FROM
    dbo.UserColor 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Users ON dbo.UserColor.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Colors ON dbo.UserColor.ColorID = dbo.Colors.ColorID
WHERE        
   (dbo.Users.UserID = 1)
```

The above query return one data but I need to show all color names and one extra field like `IsSelected` which indicate which color user had selected previously. please help me to construct the SQL . Thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You also should start using aliases in your queries, using 3 part naming all the place makes a fairly simple query like this one incredibly difficult to read. To solve your problem I would start with the Colors table because you want every row from that table, then a left join to UserColor. Your new column is simply a case expression on UserColor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you are looking for something along these lines.

```
select c.ColorID
    , c.ColorName
    , IsSelected = case when uc.ColorID is null then 0 else 1 end
from dbo.Colors c
left join dbo.UserColor uc on uc.ColorID = c.ColorID and uc.UserID = 1 --leave this in the join or it becomes an inner join
left join dbo.Users u on u.UserID = uc.UserID
```

Comment: The biggest issue in your code is your where clause. You have limited the results to show ONLY those rows where UserID = 1 which means you can't show colors that have no match. And of course most people think of using left joins rather than right joins. You start with the primary table and add additional data.

Comment: i guess the big mistake was my where clause ` WHERE        (dbo.Users.UserID = 1)` u put the same condition in join.

Comment: @CiroCorvino since they are specifically looking for a specific user it would not return multiple rows per color unless the given color is assigned to the same user more than once. It is unclear from the original post how this data is used so it is not clear if this is an issue or not. I suspect it is not an issue because a given color can only be assigned to a given user one time.

Comment: @SeanLange yes you are right, this issue happens only if one color it is reassigned to the same user.. I assumed that this case could happen.. if it doesn't happen then no problems

Answer (score 1):

You may try this version with a subquery

```
DECLARE @userID as INT = NULL;

 SELECT uc.ColorID, uc.ColorName, max(uc.IsSelected) 
 FROM
 (
  SELECT 
        c.ColorID
        , c.ColorName
        , uc.UserID
        , IsSelected = case when uc.UserID = @userID then 1 else 0 end
    FROM dbo.Colors c
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserColor uc on c.ColorID = uc.ColorID 
   ) uc
   WHERE uc.UserID = @userID OR uc.IsSelected = 0 
   GROUP BY uc.ColorID, uc.ColorName
```

in this way you get always all colors censed in dbo.Colors for the user you want selected based on previous saved choices.

You may try its working on [rextester](http://rextester.com/IUJEW96051)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want a user to have  many colors? Your structure allows a user to have that. You could simplify by moving ColorId to User table and skip UserColor table...

Comment: OK, the the structure is correct. Cant you use inner joins in stead?